# php validation for password in php

Tags: php, html, css, sql

Php validation in php for passord:

## How to create retype password validation:

help me friends for retype pass validation in php:

```
$errorMsg = "";

    if((!$email) || (!$password)){
$errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
         if(!$email){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address"; 
       } 
       else if(!$password){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Password"; 
       }
    } 


else {
echo"send to email activation";}
```

This is my form for registration

```
<tr>
      <td><div align="right">Email: </div></td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo "$email"; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Password: </div></td>
      <td><input name="password1" type="password" value="<?php echo "$password"; ?>" /> 
      <font size="-2" color="#006600">(letters or numbers only, no spaces no symbols)</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Retype Password: </div></td>
          <td><input name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo "$password"; ?>" /> 
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"></div></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: compare value $password & $password1, then check they are same or not...

Comment: And what is your question here? You are not asking how to compare those two passwords, are you?

Comment: using js check will be better ? `$('#password').val() == $('#password1').val()` on submit

Comment: @arkascha yes ur right

Answer (score 0):

you can check if $password and $password are same

`if($_POST['password '] == $_POST['password1']) echo ' Password Matches';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$errorMsg = "";
if((!$email) || (!$password)){
    $errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
    if(!$email){ 
        $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address"; 
    } 
    else if(!$password){ 
        $errorMsg .= "--- Password"; 
    }
} 
else {
    if($_POST['password1']!=$_POST['password']){
        $errorMsg .= "Passwords mismatches"; 
    }
    else{
        echo"send to email activation";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check **only** the equalness of two passwords, the **empty == empty** will **true**, so  lets check them in one expression.

### Suggestion

1. define min length of typed password e.g. 5
2. use isset because in $_POST the variable with 'password' or 'password1' key might be missing, and you'll receive **notice message**.

now check

```
...
if(isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['password1']) && strlen($_POST['password']) >=5 && $_POST['password'] === $_POST['password1']) {
     // password validated
}
...
```

also use `trim()` function getting email, but not password, because whitespaces can be part of password.

so `$email = trim($_POST['email']); // removing whitespaces from left and right`